# c# Excel 2010 VSTO Template

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I programming a Excel 2010 VSTO Template and I want to check a cell value when she is selected.

For this I use *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler*
to create the listener and *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range* for get the cell value -> *range.Cells.Value*.
But when I want to test the cell value -> *if (range.Cells.Value == null)*
I lost the select listener, the selection is not intercepted.

Do you have some ideas ?

Comment: What code do you have now? Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must keep the source object alive to be able to handle its events. So, you just need to declare the source object at the global scope (class definition), i.e. outside of the method where you subscribe to the events.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your answer
What's for you the source object*?
The value *range.Cells.Value* is a parameter of workbookEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler so the object should be alway alive

Answer (score 0):

This problem come to the dynamic type.
When I compare any of them I lost my listener *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler*